# Understanding netstat: are these TCP connections actually direct ones?

Tags: networking, tcp, internet, netstat

I am reading about networks, and in an example output table from `netstat -n` (from visiting a hypothetical website hosted from 216.40.231.195), my book shows a row that looks like this:

```
Proto  Local Address        Foreign Address     State 
TCP    192.168.4.27:57913   216.40.231.195:80   ESTABLISHED
```

Is a direct TCP connection like this even possible? 192.168.4.27 is a private IP address on the LAN, and there could be millions of network interface cards with 192.168.4.27. My computer doesn't actually have a public IP address, right? Only routers can have those.

I would expect the *actual* connection to be from 192.168.4.27:57913 to the default gateway (maybe at 192.168.4.1:50001?). I would expect the router to forward the packets to my router's public IP and port (say, 1.2.3.4:61707) and then there would be another real connection from 1.2.3.4:61707 to 216.40.231.195:80. In other words, my guess for how this breaks down is:

1. TCP connection from the PC at 192.168.4.27:57913 to the default gateway (LAN-facing network card on the router) at 192.168.4.1:50001.
2. Port forwarding from the default gateway at 192.168.4.1:50001 to the external WAN-facing network card of the router at 1.2.3.4:61707.
3. TCP connection between the router's WAN interface at 1.2.3.4:61707 and the web server at 216.40.231.195:80.

Does this accurately describe what is happening?

Also, my working definition of a "gateway" is a network interface facing the inside of a network where you send packets that go out that network into another. Is that right? I am having trouble finding a clear definition.

Comment: From the system running the netstat command's point of view, the TCP over IPv4 connection is from 192.168.4.27:57913  to 216.40.231.195:80, period. . As the gateway is out of scope here, you don't have to consider what is happening on it, nor expect that's what you described. If you really want to, anything described there and more can happen on the NAT gateway: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation#Methods_of_translation

Comment: related documentation all publicly available in IETF's RFCs (much more and more on topic certainly exists): [RFC 791](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc791 "IPv4"), [RFC 826](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc826 "ARP"), [RFC 1009](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1009 "Requirements for Internet Gateways") , [RFC 7̶9̶3̶ 9293](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9293 "TCP"), [RFC 2663](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2663 "IP Network Address Translator (NAT) Terminology and Considerations").